# WCF Service works with HTTP but not with HTTPS

Tags: azure, wcf, iis, azure-cloud-services

I have developed and published a WCF service hosted in an Azure cloud service (classic). I've installed a certificate and configured the cloud service to use the certificate. This is a certificate purchased from a CA, not a self-signed certificate. I initially suspected some issue with the certificate, but as Steffen points out in his comment, this doesn't seem to be the case. I can send a POST request via HTTP, and get a 200 response. But if I try to send a POST request via HTTPS I get a 404 response. This is the only difference between the two requests. Using HTTPS is required.

I've configured IIS to send detailed error messages for both local and remote calls, but I'm still getting no information beyond the basic 404, not found.

Here are the bindings and endpoints sections from the service definition (.csdef) file.

```
<Bindings>
    <Binding name="HttpsIn" endpointName="HttpsIn" />
    <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
</Bindings>

<Endpoints>
    <InputEndpoint name="HttpsIn" protocol="https" port="443" certificate="mycertificate" />
    <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="80" />  
</Endpoints>
```

And here is the bindings section from the web.config file:

```
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="HttpsIn">
          <security mode="Transport"></security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

This works, returning a 200 response:

```
POST http://mydomain/myservice.svc HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: mydomain
Content-Length: 600
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "myclass/myaction"

<?xml version="1.0" etc, etc
```

This fails, returning a 404 response:

```
POST https://mydomain/myservice.svc HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: mydomain
Content-Length: 600
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "myclass/myaction"

<?xml version="1.0" etc, etc
```

The response:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 20 Jun 2019 09:40:02 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

I tried making the changes suggested by Abraham Quian below. My service config was mostly as indicated by Abraham, except that it didn't have the aspNetCompatibilityEnabled attribute or the protocolMapping section, so I added those. My IIS binding was as indicated by Abraham but was using a specific IP address rather than 'All Assigned' so I made that change also. Following these changes I was getting a service activation exception. The error message indicated a problem with the aspNetCompatibilityEnabled attribute so I took that back out again. I was now getting a 503, service unavailable, when attempting to browse to the site remotely, but I was able to browse to the site when logged on to the server. This looked like it might be a problem with the IP address, so I changed the IIS binding to use the specific IP address again. I'm now back where I started - the service works via http, but I get the 404 when trying to call it via https.

To sum up, I can display the WSDL in a browser (mydomain/myservice.svc?wsdl) using either HTTP or HTTPS. I can call the SOAP action method using GET using either HTTP or HTTPS. This of course does not return the desired result, because the method needs to be called using POST, but it returns the content of the 'you have created a service' page. The 404 happens only with the combination of HTTPS and POST.

```
HTTP + GET = 200, 
HTTPS + GET = 200, 
HTTP + POST = 200, 
HTTPS + POST = 404.
```

Comment: This is totally unrelated to a SSL certificate. A 404 response means that the page does not exist - and you get this response after a successful TLS handshake, i.e. the certificate works. Why your server returns 404 on this specific request is unknown but it has nothing to do with the certificate.

Comment: Thanks for that Steffen. I've edited the question to take your comment into account.

Comment: Have you specified the `<security mode="Transport">` in your web.config ? Have you google WCF Https binding ?

Comment: Hi Thomas, yes, security mode = "Transport", and yes, I've googled, but I certainly would not claim to understand everything that I've found. I'll add information about the binding to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Buddy, it seems that there is something wrong with the process of publishing the service over https.
Please use the following configuration to enable https and http.
**Server configuration.**

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <protocolMapping>
      <add scheme="https" binding="basicHttpsBinding"/>
      <add scheme="http" binding="basicHttpBinding"/>
    </protocolMapping>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Then we add http binding and https binding in IIS site binding module.
**IIS site binding**
[image]
One thing must be noted that the service is not Restful, it is simply works in SOAP message. We could invoke it by using a client proxy. Like below.
**Client side.**

```
ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client("BasicHttpsBinding_IService1");
            try
            {
                var result = client.GetData(34);
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
```

Client configuration.

```
    <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
            <binding name="BasicHttpsBinding_IService1">
                <security mode="Transport" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://vabqia969vm:11000/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
        <endpoint address="https://vabqia969vm:11001/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpsBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
            name="BasicHttpsBinding_IService1" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

The above client proxy class(service1client) is generated by adding service reference in my project.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Hi Abraham. Thanks for that. I tried making the changes indicated, but I'm now getting a 503, service unavailable error. I'll edit the question to add in the details.

Comment: After you applied my configuration, could you access the below service address over HTTPS?
https://mydomain/myservice.svc?wsdl
Besides, please enable windows feature for supporting WCF.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEddz.png

Comment: Hi Abraham. Before I removed the aspNetCompatibilityEnabled attribute, no, after I removed it, yes. Re the WCF services, HTTP Activation and TCP Port Sharing were already enabled. I enabled the other three also but it has made no difference. I can access the WSDL in a browser using either HTTP or HTTPS. I can call the SOAP action method using GET using either HTTP or HTTPS (this results in the 'you have created a service' page being returned). I can call the SOAP action method via POST using HTTP and get the expected response. I just can't call the SOAP action method via POST using HTTPS.

Comment: What is the error details?  Could it generate the https service endpoint in a separate project when calling the service by adding service reference? Have you established the trust relationship between the server and the client?  Like following,
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate
              {
                  return true;
              };
Alternatively, we could install the server certificate in our ROOT CA.

Comment: Hi Abraham. Currently there are no details, just the 404. I've pasted the complete response in the question. Or did you mean the error when the aspNetCompatibilityEnabled attribute was present? I can get the details of that error message if you think it will help. I'll try the separate project idea and report back. The 'client' for the purpose of these tests is Fiddler. I do have a test client, which returns the same 404 result. I'll add the code that deals with certificate validation to the question, as it's a bit long for a comment.

Comment: Re the suggestion about adding the certificate to the root CA - do you mean on the server or on the client PC? Do you think there might still be an issue with the certificate? I thought we'd ruled that out? See Steffen's comment above.

Comment: The test client sets certificate validation mode to none, using the code below. But please not that the same issue occurs when testing using Fiddler, independently of the test client.

lient.ChannelFactory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SslCertificateAuthentication =
                new System.ServiceModel.Security.X509ServiceCertificateAuthentication();
            client.ChannelFactory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SslCertificateAuthentication.CertificateValidationMode = 
                System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.None;

Comment: I tried creating a new project and adding the service reference. Initially the generated files included some references to ```http://servername``` instead of ```https://domainname``` and a "Protocol=http" and I got the message 'provided URI sceme is invalid'. I edited these and added "<security mode="Transport">" and "<transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>" to the config file. I'm now getting the same 404 result from the new project.

Comment: If the project does not generate the HTTPS endpoint, it indicates that the service is not working properly over https. By default, Azure app Service project provides unified Https certificates, so the https protocol is enabled by default.
Without the usage of your certificate, when the WCF service is released, can you access it by adding a service reference in a separate console program? At least on my side, it all worked as scheduled and worked very well.
My WCF service application uses the default template except for the Appconfig, the configuration just likes the aforementioned.

Comment: Hi Abraham. "The service is not working properly over HTTPS" is exactly the issue I am trying to resolve. This is not an app service. It's a cloud service (classic). The service works fine without a certificate over HTTP. But that's not an option. Use of a server certificate and HTTPS is required. Everything I've read so far leads me to suspect that the problem lies somewhere in the bindings. I just can't figure out exactly where or what.